# How to get IE9 settings from client (how to export IE9 settings)?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

After some googling online, I found a post here on SO that I thought would help me (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940884/336384).

Unfortunately, the instructions didn't match what I saw.

In Windows 7 I ran: 
    gpedit.msc 
    -> Local Computer Policy 
    -> Computer Configuration 
    -> Administrative Templates 
    -> Windows Components 
    -> Right click on Internet Explorer

The only menu options I had were:

- Filter On
- Filter Options
- Re-Apply Filter (grayed out)
- All Tasks

  - Filter On
  - Filter Options
  - Re-Apply Filter (grayed out)
- Help

There was no "Export Settings" or "Export List" type of option.

How can I export all settings from an instance of IE9 and import them into my instance of IE9? I've already tried manually entering settings from screenshots, but the behavior between the two browsers remain different.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit of investigating based on a hunch (as I never had to do this, personally).

From what I found, IE settings are stored in the Windows Registry. You should only have to have him export the registry settings under this folder:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer`

From what I can tell, it appears to have all the settings relevent to Internet Explorer (minus things stored elsewhere, like Favorites lists).

How to interpret these stored settings, however, are occasionally obvious, but sometimes not so much. You'll have to figure out what to do with them, after you get them.

To get them on your machine, you should just be able to merge these settings into your own Registry. However, I cannot guarantee that this is the only place where settings are stored, and that doing so may break something else. Backup your data, and make sure you have restore points to go back to in case something goes awry.

Answer (score 0):

File->import export from browser window can be used

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that will only import/export Favorites, Feeds, and Cookies. Does it also include browser settings like the security settings, advanced settings, etc?

Comment: No it does not include  include browser settings like the security settings

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool dedicated to export the IE security settings: [IEZoneAnalyzer](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fdcc/archive/2011/09/22/iezoneanalyzer-v3-5-with-zone-map-viewer.aspx). It only retrieves security settings by zone (internet, trusted sites...) but it is a real time-saver when solving those weird cases where "it works everywhere except on this IE".

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you tried, the issue is that you looked under Local Computer Policy instead of User Configuration.

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274846:

> - Open the Group Policy Editor by using Microsoft Management Console (MMC).
> - Locate and click Internet Explorer Maintenance under Windows Settings in User Configuration.
> - Right-click Internet Explorer Maintenance, and then click Preference Mode.
>
> If a policy is already defined, you must click Reset Browser Settings
>   before you can place this policy in Preference mode. When you reset
>   the browser settings, any policy settings that are specified to that
>   Group Policy are reset.

FWIW, although IE settings are all stored in the registry, they are somewhat scattered and so hard to manage that way.  If you aren't going to use a tool like the IEAK, then GPO is probably the best way to go.